# Rails image_tag path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I need to display image in my public folder. But it's url is generating using db, so in my controller i do something like this(also is that good?):

```
@link_gra_art = LinkGraArt.find_by_LGA_ART_ID(params[:id])    
@graphics = Graphic.find_by_GRA_ID(@link_gra_art.LGA_GRA_ID)
```

And in my view i must have something like this:

```
= image_tag("grafpath".@graphics.GRA_ID."/"@link_gra_art.LGA_ART_ID., :alt => "test image")
```

I didn't know how to kombine such string, becouse in php for this i will write "".$var."", how is this in rails? via dot, or via what?

Also is that way of getting data from model via another model good?

DB is not my, so tables are huge, and have non-rails-way written fields.

Answer (score 2):

[Variable interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation) in ruby is done with `#{...}`:

```
image_tag("grafpath#{@graphics.GRA_ID}/#{@link_gra_art.LGA_ART_ID}", ...
```

Or you can just concatenate string with `+` (what PHP does with `.`).